# How do I access old unlocked notes that I forgot the password to without any ID?

Tags: iphone, notes.app

Is there a way to access old notes that you forgot the password to? Without touch ID or face ID? I've tried every combo I could think of.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Do you mean accessing old _locked_ notes?

Comment: Do you have locked notes within Notes where you forgot the password for? Or did you forget the password for your iCloud account? Please be more specific about the actual problem you are facing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear if your Notes are on a local device or iCloud whose password you forgot.

1. If you are asking about retrieving your Notes that have synced to iCloud, then you must be able to first log in to your iCloud account with the account that owns these notes. There is no other way to retrieve these notes even if they are not locked with an additional password.
2. If the Notes are stored in your local device but you forgot the passcode of your device, then you also need to first be able to get into your iOS device to access the Notes. So, unfortunately, there is no way to retrieve your Notes if you lost access. Instead of the native Notes app, you may consider using EverNote, Google Keeps or other cross-platform note applications instead where you can reset your account when you forget the password.